# How do i Include css from static folder in a nextjs react project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm fetching data from api call in ***_document.js***, and based on data putting condition to include css using ***Link*** tag.

I was trying to include css file from ***public/static/*** folder in ***_document.js*** or ***layout.js*** file,
but not working.

*layout.js* file

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head'
...
<Head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/static/ed_style.css" />
</Head>
...
```

Comment: you can do 

`import './folderpath/file.css';`

Comment: I'm working on global sharing of data in all pages and based on data coming from api call, I'm putting condition to include css using <Link /> tag. so can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your link is not correct. You can try an absolute one like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/ed_style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use **import NextHead from 'next/head'** instead of **import Head from 'next/head'**
2. Create your own Head component :

   ```
   const Head = () => (
    <NextHead>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/ed_style.css" />
    </NextHead>
   )
   ```
3. And then in your layout.js

   ```
   import Head from '../components/head.js'
   ```

Comment: where do you put your condition ?

Comment: Your solution is working but,

As static folder is deprected. (Checkout this https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/errors/static-dir-deprecated.md).

I moved static folder to public folder, Now its not working

Comment: Yes, there is a conflict with public/static , if you named your folder with static files under public, as you see from doc, you don't need the `public` directory name to be included. However, if you just put `/static`, it is trying to point to the default static folder which doesn't exist in your case.

Comment: Okay, Got this. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for you time.
I got solution.

I have put my css file *ed_style.css* directly to public folder and accessed as below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ed_style.css" />
```

and Its working